# Flutter access session data (in particular Firebase.currentUser) synchronously

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, session-state

I must confess that I am new to Flutter. This feels like a very trivial question to me and yet, I can't seem to find an answer. Perhaps my Googling is sub par this evening and if so, I apologise in advance, but I did try..

At any rate, my problem is as follows:
In main.dart, I have:

```dart
  Future <bool> _getCurrentUser () async {
    user = await _auth.currentUser();
    setState(() {
        if (user == null){
            FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
        }
    });  
  }
```

Or, in other words, if the user is not currently logged in, I invoke `FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();`. This is because I'd like to allow the user to navigate through certain screens without having to login.
However, I'd also like the behaviour to vary when clicking on the `drawer` [scaffold] icon.
If the user is logged in (as opposed to the app invoking `signInAnonymously()` on their behalf) , I want to display a full options menu, otherwise, I want to direct them to the login/registration screen.
I looked into https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_session as well as `SharedPreferences` but they both seem to operate solely in async mode so, the menu renders before a response is returned (I have a custom, stateful, drawer widget which I set as my `endDrawer` attribute, so:

```
Scaffold(
...
endDrawer: DrawerCode(),
...
```

In general, I anticipate needing the same sort of mechanism for other uses in the future.
Any advice as to the common practice would be most welcome.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Use FutureBuilder.

Comment: Thank you, @TirthPatel. I am just looking at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html now.